# Asp.net dynamicdata code first entity framework 6 error when using a table named "url"

Tags: entity-framework-6, dynamic-data

I have a strange error, I'm using code first entity framework 6 with a dynamic data web app.  Whenever I have a relationship to a table called "URL" (or "Url"), I get the following error when editing the related object:

> 'microsoft.aspnet.entitydatasource.entitydatasourcewrapper' does not contain a property with the name "Urls"

I can change the name of the class to anything else and it works.  (I used 'siteurl').  Why is this word special?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the name URL is being pluralized by dynamic data site.  That's what happened to me for a field name.  I unchecked the "Pluralize or singularize generated object names" on the "Choose Your Database Objects and Settings dialog box in the Model and it worked.  :)